# Searching for objects with a certain storage class on Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I've been archiving my data on S3 to Glacier, and I thought I had moved everything. However, my activity report still shows that I have a few items left that is stored in RRS. I've browsed my buckets, but I can't find any objects that have the storage class RRS. Is there a better way to find out what objects are still stored as RRS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now generate a report that displays all the storage class for each object in a bucket with [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can download the Bucket Explorer latest version from here: [Last Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/be-download.html)
Using it you can differentiate between the RRS objects, Glacier objects and Standard object using color combination.

See the screenshots:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

CloudBerry Explorer FREE/PRO is also a good fit for this:

[image]